Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined React Native
Here is the error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Here is the code:
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { FocusAwareStatusBar } from "./_layout";

export default function Home(){
    const [totals, setTotals] = useState({
        Clinical: 0,
        Extracurricular: 0,
        Shadowing: 0,
        Volunteer: 0,
        Research: 0,
      });
      const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
      const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserData = async () => {
          try {
            const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
            const userData = jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
            if (userData) {
              setUserName(userData.name);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching user data", error);
          }
        };
    
        const checkDarkModeStatus = async () => {
          try {
            const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isDark");
            if (jsonValue != null) {
              const darkMode = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
              setIsDarkMode(darkMode);
            } else {
              console.log("no theme settings found!");
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error checking dark mode status", error);
          }
        };
    
        checkDarkModeStatus();
        fetchUserData();
      }, []);
    
      const calculateTotals = async () => {
        try {
          const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("formData");
          const formData = jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : [];
    
          const newTotals = {
            Clinical: 0,
            Extracurricular: 0,
            Shadowing: 0,
            Volunteer: 0,
            Research: 0,
          };
    
          formData.forEach((data) => {
            if (data.number && data.category) {
              newTotals[data.category] += parseFloat(data.number);
            }
          });
    
          setTotals(newTotals);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error calculating totals", error);
        }
      };
    
      useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
          calculateTotals();
        }, [])
      );
    
      const renderItem = (item) => (
        <View
          key={item.category}
          style={isDarkMode ? styles.smallCardDark : styles.smallCard}
        >
          <Text style={styles.value}>{item.value}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.label}>{item.category}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    
      const data = [
        { category: "Clinical", value: totals.Clinical },
        { category: "Extracurricular", value: totals.Extracurricular },
        { category: "Shadowing", value: totals.Shadowing },
        { category: "Volunteer", value: totals.Volunteer },
        { category: "Research", value: totals.Research },
      ];
    
      return (
        <>
          <FocusAwareStatusBar hidden backgroundColor="#ecf0f1" />
    
          {isDarkMode == false && (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <StatusBar
                barStyle="light-content"
                backgroundColor="transparent"
                translucent
              />
              <View style={styles.bannerContainer}>
                <Image
                  source={require("../../assets/banner.jpeg")} // Local banner image
                  style={styles.bannerImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <LinearGradient
                  colors={["rgba(0,0,0,0)", "#529bbb"]} // Transparent to desired color
                  style={styles.overlay}
                />
              </View>
              <LinearGradient
                colors={["#529bbb", "#eeaeca"]}
                style={styles.backgroundGradient}
              >
                <View style={styles.centralContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.centralCard}>
                    <Text style={styles.greeting}>Hello {userName}</Text>
                    <View style={styles.row}>{data.map(renderItem)}</View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </LinearGradient>
            </View>
          )}
          {isDarkMode && (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <StatusBar
                barStyle="light-content"
                backgroundColor="transparent"
                translucent
              />
              <View style={styles.bannerContainer}>
                <Image
                  source={require("../../assets/banner_wb.png")} // Local banner image
                  style={styles.bannerImage}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
              </View>
              <LinearGradient
                colors={["#181818", "#181818"]}
                style={styles.backgroundGradient}
              >
                <View style={styles.centralContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.centralCardDark}>
                    <Text style={styles.greeting}>Hello {userName}</Text>
                    <View style={styles.row}>{data.map(renderItem)}</View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </LinearGradient>
            </View>
          )}
        </>
      );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      color: "#EEAAEA",
    },
    bannerContainer: {
      position: "relative",
      width: "100%",
      height: 250, // Adjust the height as needed to move the picture down
      overflow: "hidden",
    },
    bannerImage: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      backgroundColor: "#232323",
      borderColor: "#EEAAEA",
      borderBottomWidth: 6,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
    },
    overlay: {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    },
    backgroundGradient: {
      flex: 1,
      width: "100%",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
    },
    centralContainer: {
      width: "90%",
      marginTop: -125, // Adjust the margin top value to move the container higher
      alignItems: "center", // Center horizontally
  
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
    },
    centralCard: {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  
      padding: 20,
      borderRadius: 10,
      marginTop: 20,
      marginBottom: 20,
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.1,
      shadowRadius: 4,
      elevation: 5,
      alignItems: "center",
  
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      borderColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 3,
      color: "white",
    },
    centralCardDark: {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  
      padding: 20,
      borderRadius: 10,
      marginTop: 20,
      marginBottom: 20,
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.1,
      shadowRadius: 4,
      elevation: 5,
      alignItems: "center",
  
      backgroundColor: "#232323",
  
      color: "white",
    },
    greeting: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: "bold",
      marginBottom: 20,
      color: "white",
    },
    row: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      justifyContent: "center",
    },
    smallCard: {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      padding: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
      margin: 5,
      width: "45%", // Adjust width to fit two columns with margins
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
      },
  
      shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      shadowRadius: 4,
      elevation: 5,
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
  
      borderColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
    smallCardDark: {
      padding: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
      margin: 5,
      width: "45%", // Adjust width to fit two columns with margins
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
      },
  
      shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      shadowRadius: 4,
      elevation: 5,
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "#3E3E3E",
    },
    label: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 12,
      color: "white",
    },
    value: {
      fontSize: 20,
      color: "white",
      fontWeight: "700",
      marginTop: 5,
    },
  });

This was working before, when I was using Expo Go and React Navigation, but when I switched to a development build and Expo Router, I am encountering this problem. This was a screen that could be navigated to using router.navigate("/home");. Also I used this in a tabbar like this:
    import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
    import { Home } from "lucide-react-native";

    export default function TabLayout() {
      return (
        <Tabs screenOptions={{ tabBarActiveTintColor: 'blue', headerShown: false }}>
          <Tabs.Screen
            name="Home"
            options={{
              title: 'Home',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Home size={28} name="home" color={color} />,
            }}
          />
          <Tabs.Screen
            name="index"
            options={{
              title: 'Index',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Home size={28} name="cog" color={color} />,
            }}
          />
        </Tabs>
      );
    }


What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Share your use of the component. Where was it imported and used?

@ChukwujiobiCanon I used the component in a router.navigate("/home"); and in a tabbar component as shown above.

"lucide-react-native"? I don’t know your current setup but it probably should be a relative path instead.
